# Curl POST Form with Image File to Form

Tags: node.js, bash, curl, terminal, sails.js

I am trying to POST a JPEG image from a particular file directory to the server curl. This is what I typed:

```
curl -v -include --form filedata='/home/pi/Documents/2014-01-18-09:11:25.jpeg' http://hostdomain.me/file/upload
```

Upon executing this command, the following is returned from the Terminal:

```
* Couldn't find host rdnvpfwnwk.localtunnel.me in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to rdnvpfwnwk.localtunnel.me port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.34.58.73...
* connected
* Connected to rdnvpfwnwk.localtunnel.me (192.34.58.73) port 80 (#0)
> POST /file/upload HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: rdnvpfwnwk.localtunnel.me
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 186
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------affc91df7bc3
>
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Server: nginx
Server: nginx
< Date: Sat, 18 Jan 2014 11:44:39 GMT
Date: Sat, 18 Jan 2014 11:44:39 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 9245
Content-Length: 9245
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Sails <sailsjs.org>
X-Powered-By: Sails <sailsjs.org>
* Added cookie sails.sid="s%3AAucWnGhDSzZSGB_tBgSXJoU2.DMQ4FuVVRRGLFGheMgr4CvIFUICCiP9Gqd5GIjRevA8" for domain rdnvpfwnwk.localtunnel.me, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: sails.sid=s%3AAucWnGhDSzZSGB_tBgSXJoU2.DMQ4FuVVRRGLFGheMgr4CvIFUICCiP9Gqd5GIjRevA8; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: sails.sid=s%3AAucWnGhDSzZSGB_tBgSXJoU2.DMQ4FuVVRRGLFGheMgr4CvIFUICCiP9Gqd5GIjRevA8; Path=/; HttpOnly

* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

When using the form on the site it sends properly. Here is the form:

```
<form id="uploadForm"
enctype="multipart/form-data"
action="/file/upload"
method="post">
<input type="file" id="userPhotoInput" name="userPhoto" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
curl -v -include --form "userPhoto=@/home/pi/Documents/2014-01-18-09:11:25.jpeg" http://hostdomain.me/file/upload
                         ^^^^^^^^^ ^
```

Comment: I get Unable to parse HTTP body :: { [Error: Request aborted] status:4 400 } on the server and 504 gateway timeout in response the curl in terminal. any ideas?

Comment: you can install firebug on firefox; then goto Net tab and upload the file to your site; you can see your request; right click on request and select _copy as cURL_ ; after this if you see successful upload file you can paste the curl on bash and run it..